# android custom listview with unbound data item

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, android-edittext

I have created an activity that contains a listview with a custom row view.

Row View:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="1dp" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemID"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemDescription"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemRequested"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/itemCompleted"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="number" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

I am binding an ArrayList to my list view with a custom adapter class I created. Here is my Item class:

```
public class Item {

    @SerializedName("ItemID")
    public int ItemID;

    @SerializedName("ItemDescription")
    public String ItemDescription;

    @SerializedName("ItemModel")
    public String ItemModel;    

    @SerializedName("ItemCartons")
    public int ItemCartons;

}
```

What I am doing is showing my ArrayList in the activity listview with the custom layout which works perfectly. When the user is viewing the listview I want them to be able to enter a value in the itemCompleted EditText control so I can update the item with the completed quantity. When my update event is triggered (button on actionbar) I am iterating through the listview and getting the values out of the custom layout like so:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < mListView.getCount(); i++) {
            View v = mListView.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
            TextView requested = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.itemRequested);
            EditText completed = (EditText) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.itemCompleted);
            TextView itemID = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemID);

            int req = Integer.parseInt((String) requested.getText());
            int comp = Integer.parseInt(completed.getText().toString());
            int id = Integer.parseInt((String) itemID.getText());

            if (comp <= req) {
                //update item here

            } else {
                // qty is too much
                return;
            }
        }
```

My problem is that I am unable to retrieve the value that was entered in the itemCompleted EditText control. It is always pulling the default value and not the value entered by the user. Is there a way I can pull the entered value from the EditText?

Comment: Are you getting ALL default values, or only some default values?

Comment: Only the completed control can be changed, the rest of the items in the row I get the correct values out. Only the control that can be modified gives me the default value when I iterate through the listview

Comment: Solved my problem after reading [this][1] SO question


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735936/android-edittexts-within-listview-bound-to-custom-arrayadapter-keeping-track