# edittext doesn't work on one click when it's in iconic adapter

Tags: android, android-edittext, getview

I'm trying to input some text in the EditText object.
but It doesn't work well. I think it's due to iconic adapter.
At once I click it, it loses its focus immediately.

What am I supposed to do?

```
private String[] items = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        IconicAdapter iAdapter = new IconicAdapter(this);
        list.setAdapter(iAdapter);
    }

    class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
        Activity context;
        IconicAdapter(Activity context) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            super(context, R.layout.scr_buc_list_item, items);
            this.context = context;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scr_buc_list_item, null);

            EditText listName = (EditText)row.findViewById(R.id.txtView);
            listName.setText(items[position]);

            return row;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work well"? Define what doesn't work

Comment: Just copy the accepted answer hear and tweak it to your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735936/android-edittexts-within-listview-bound-to-custom-arrayadapter-keeping-track